# Web Api 2 Controller and Handler have five second delay between them

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

Recently the web requests on my Web Api 2 w/ Entity Framework 6.1 server have taken a drastic reduction in speed. Adding ~5000ms to all requests that query the database. I've spent the last three days ripping my hair out trying to figure it out.

Setup:

- Web Api 2.2
- Entity Framework 6.1.1
- Autofac for IoC, DbContext is InstancePerLifetimeScope() along with everything else.
- One custom HttpParameterBinding for getting entity id's from an access token. This does query the db.
- Only one DelegatingHandler, for logging requests

What I've done:

- Pre generated views, slight improvement
- Reduced properties in entities we query, no improvement
- Turned off AutoTrackChanges, no improvement
- Tried AsNoTracking() on a number of requests, no improvement
- Profiling with Ant Performance Profiler, nothing useful
- Profiling database with SQL Management Studio, the queries are all fast

Why do I say there's a delay between the handler and the  controller? I timed it with DateTime.Now at the beginning and the end  of the controller action, *1745ms* The logging handler does a time before and after the await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken), *6234ms*. I timed the binding as well, only 2ms.

That's *4489ms* of time that's unaccounted for. Other requests have similar timings. It happens after the logging handler get's the request and reports it but before the binding starts. What happens in there? Where is it coming from? We don't have any async void methods that spin off, we don't have any per request actions that should take that long. Totally stumped.

Edit: Repeating the same request does not improve the performance. I don't believe one hit performance is the issue, it's consistently poor.

Comment: If you do a 2nd request the exact same way is it much faster? There are a lot of first hit penalties to keep in mind, spinning up the app pool and loading the assemblies for any .net application, ef loading metadata from your database the first time it's called.

Comment: I would be looking for something related to the async calls. Size of thread pool, any deadlock-like behavior (for example waiting on a task), etc.

Comment: Are you aware of any changes to the app pool being made before the speed reduction, or any windows updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate the help, I did end up finding the answer.

We had services that were being injected into the controllers and their constructors were using potentially async calls that preloaded some stuff. Changing it to use *AsyncLazy* was the solution.

Potentially helpful steps to those in similar situations, enumerated now.

Ever played the board game Guess Who? That's strikingly similar to debugging. You want to ask that knock down half of the potential questions. Don't start with "is it this specific method that I felt dirty with", instead start with:

- What works and what doesn't work? Find the the differences. That's your problem set.
- Narrow down the problem set with generic questions. Find the shared similarities and get rid of them. Is it async calls? (Thanks commenter) Is it deadlock-like stuff? (Thanks again). Is it first hit or initial loading?
- Once you've removed the shared similarities it's time to start commenting out code. I narrowed it down to a constructor that was getting injected with three objects and not doing any work it's self. When it wasn't the first two objects I knew where my problem was!